# QuickTime Player audio recordings editing

Tags: audio, software-recommendation, quicktime

As per [here](https://www.movavi.com/learning-portal/how-to-record-mp3-on-mac.html), The QuickTime Player is capable of

> perform simple editing tasks, such as trimming the audio file, splitting it into clips, merging and rearranging sound clips.

I using the latest MacOS (v14.2.1, BuildVersion 23C71), but find the operation not working as I expected, or at least counter-intuitive.

So I want to

trim the leading and ending silence,
splitting my audio recording into clips, remove the unwanted parts/clips, is that possible?
else can I save my split audio recording into different files?
else, any tool can do such audio recordings editing please.

Comment: I'd suggest tools like Audacity, or Sound Studio.